# Math in Python Code File not the Same in Console

Tags: python, powershell, console, decimal, truncate

I'm trying to find out what's going on here. I'm running through [Learn Python the Hard Way](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex3.html) book, and it got to the point where it wanted me to type out complex math: like those speed-math problems you may have gotten in elementary school. The problem is when I run the problem in the file from console, it produces an answer different than what you would find if you typed the problem into the console directly.

My example being thus:

[image]

The first line is the problem with the result that comes from the file being the following line. Then I replicate the *exact same* problem within the console to get the following result.

The site is insinuating that one would assume to see the number round down, while the author says it's truncating the number, or ["dropping the fractional part after the decimal"](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex3.html#common-student-questions). I see neither of those things happening.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here? I currently have Python 2.7 installed.

Comment: And this is one of many reasons why you shouldn't use LPTHW, chief among them being that Zed thinks Python 3 is an untested fad. He's wrong. Install the latest version of Python 3, then take the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) on python.org. After that, check [here](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F) for other tutorials and educational material. Reddit's [r/python](https://www.reddit.com/r/python) and [r/learnpython](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/wiki/index) groups have lots of tutorial and other info on their sites as well.

Comment: @MattDMo: Zed said you would say that...but I'll take a look anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both operands in `1/4` are integers. Python doesn't auto-convert the result of that operation to float. PowerShell does. Hence Python subtracts 0, whereas PowerShell subtracts 0.25.

Change the Python statement to this:

```python
3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1.0 / 4 + 6                           # returns 6.75
```

and you'll get the same result as in PowerShell.

For PowerShell to give the same result as Python you need to [emulate an integer division](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176879.aspx):

```bsh
3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - [Math]::Floor([int]1 / [int]4) + 6    # returns 7
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you are performing arithmetic in Python. In the second, you are using the Windows console. They use different rules to evaluate such expressions -- notably the `1/4` portion (Python does not use floats unless you tell it to, so the result is `0`).

I get the same answer when I compare a Python script vs the Python console:

```
# Python script.
$ python -c 'print 3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 / 4 + 6'
7

# The Python console.
$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jul 30 2016, 18:49:54)
>>> print 3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 / 4 + 6
7
```